# Two Panels in one JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, panels

i have two Panels and want them to be shown in my JFrame, but when i try it like this, i can only see the second one. Can someone please help me? :(

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainWindow {

CardLayout layout;
JFrame frame;
Player panel1;
Block panel2;

public MainWindow() {
    frame = new JFrame("Rechteck");
    panel1 = new Player();
    panel2 = new Block();
    panel1.addKeyListener(new KeyListen(panel1));
    frame.add(panel1);
    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 4):

You have added both your panels to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of your `JFrame`—only one can occupy that location,. This will be the last one added, `panel2` in this case.

To allow the panels occupy the space evenly, you could use `GridLayout`:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
```

*Aside:* Better to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) when registering key events for components in Swing.

Comment: thanks. but there is still one problem: there are 2 parts of the frame for every panel

Comment: The above layout will lay out 2 panels. Do you have more? Also are you using that CardLayout? What are layouts inside the 2 panels?

Answer (score 1):

Create a JPanel add that to the JFrame. Add panel1 and panel2 to the new panel.  JFrame can only have one child, usually set by calling JFrame.setContentPane().

Comment: `JFrame` is a container, technically, it could have any number of children (and in fact it does).  The implementation of `JFrame` redirects calls to `add` and `remove` (and other container management methods) to the content pane.  You could simply change the layout manager to something like `GridLayout` instead.  There's no need for third pane - IMHO